# i got error on rpi camera. Camera is good and i still got this error

Tags: camera

I get these error messages:

```
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

Comment: Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Answer (score 0):

The error code `ENOSPC` usually means that the file system is full.

You can check the available space with the `df` command.